# Event only triggers if double click an element from sap.m.List

Tags: list, events, click, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 splitapp with a detail page. This detail page contains a list with `ObjectListItem`s. I want to listen to a press/selection of this item, but I always have to press two times to an element, else the event does not get triggered.

Does anybody know  what is the reason?

Thanks and best regards

Detail XML

```
<Page 
    id="myJobsPage"
    title="{i18n>myJobsTitle}">

    <List
        id="myJobsMasterList"
        inset="false"
        items="{testkunden}">

            <ObjectListItem 
                id="myJobsListItem"
                visible="true"
                title="{job}"
                number="{offen}"
                numberUnit="Euro"
                press="onMyJobsListItem" 
                type="Active">

                <!-- visible part -->
                <ObjectAttribute 
                id="Gpart123"
                text="Partner: {gpart}"
                visible="true" />

                <ObjectAttribute 
                    id="Anrede123"
                    text="{anrede}"
                    visible="true" />

                <ObjectAttribute 
                    id="Name123"
                    text="{vorname} {nachname}"
                    visible="true" />

                <ObjectAttribute 
                    id="Strasse123"
                    text="{strasse} {hausnr}"
                    visible="true" />

            </ObjectListItem>

        <!-- <ObjectStatus text="{i18n>myJobsObjectStatus}" />  -->         
    </List>
</Page>

</mvc:View>
```

Controller

```js
onMyJobsListItem: function(event){
   console.log("only triggers if click twice");
  
};
```

**UPDATE:**
Splitapp Root View

```
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="mobile.splitapp.controller.App"
                displayBlock="true"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
                xmlns="sap.m" >

                <App id="app">

                    <SplitApp id="splitapp" >
                        <masterPages>
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="mobile.splitapp.view.Master" id="master1" />
                        </masterPages>

                        <detailPages>
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="mobile.splitapp.view.MyJobs" id="myJobsPage" />
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="mobile.splitapp.view.DisconnectionOrder" id="disconnectionOrderPage" /> 
                        </detailPages>
                    </SplitApp>

                </App>

            </mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a running example of your code (see below of [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tepevifife/edit?html,output), and the [updated jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qupabelase/edit?html,output)) and it runs just fine! Since you did not post your "surrounding" code I cannot tell what's wrong. But as you can see in the example below the event is triggered directly after the first press...

Cann you see a difference to your code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->
 
        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
            
              <App>
                <SplitApp>
                  
                  <masterPages>
                    <Page 
                        id="myJobsPage"
                        title="Master Page">

                        <List
                            id="myJobsMasterList"
                            inset="false"
                            items="{/Customers}">

                                <ObjectListItem 
                                    id="myJobsListItem"
                                    visible="true"
                                    title="{CompanyName}"
                                    number="{offen}"
                                    numberUnit="Euro"
                                    press="onMyJobsListItem" 
                                    type="Active"/>
                                
                        </List>
                    </Page>
                  </masterPages>
                  
                  <detailPages>
                    <Page 
                        title="Detail Page">

                        <List
                            inset="false"
                            items="{/Customers}">

                                <ObjectListItem 
                                    visible="true"
                                    title="{CompanyName}"
                                    number="{offen}"
                                    numberUnit="Euro"
                                    press="onMyJobsListItem" 
                                    type="Active"/>
                                
                        </List>
                    </Page>
                  </detailPages>
                  
                </SplitApp>
              </App>
 
            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
 
                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
                    onInit : function () {
 
                        this.getView().setModel(
                            new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", {
                                json : true,
                                useBatch : false
                            })
                        ); 
                    },
                  
                    onMyJobsListItem: function(event){
                      alert("press");
                    }
                  
                });
 
                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
 
            });
        </script>
 
    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see a difference and there is no effect with this code. Maybe I have a problem with the splitapp? I will post the other code.

Comment: What do you mean there is no effect (make sure to run the jsbin link)? If you press any list item you can see the alert box, right? I updated the code as well...